# IOException while trying to call su on rooted phone

Tags: java, android, root, su

I am developing some system level application, that will interact with native applications that must run as a root, since they are talking with device drivers directly.

The phone is rooted /system/xbin/su is accessible. I've also set-up the privilege level for this application as `signed`, but still, I can't call `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` with `su` command specifically.
 
I can even run `reboot` command like this (but only when I set `setenforce 0`), but not `su`. SELinux does not report anything when doing this.